# Python: Table with too much data off screen and not scrollable

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with this function that create a table and two scrollbar, but when its created the frame mantain the dimension but the value are printed off frame, and the scroll event doesn't work at least for the vertical

```
 #The function for the table
[...]
text_area = tk.Canvas(frame, background="black", width=dim_frame[0], height=dim_frame[1], scrollregion=(0,0,dim_frame[0],dim_frame[1]))
    hscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=text_area.xview)
    vscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=text_area.yview)
    text_area['xscrollcommand'] = hscroll.set
    text_area['yscrollcommand'] = vscroll.set

    hscroll.pack(side=TOP, fill="x")
    text_area.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="both")
    vscroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill="y")
    i=2
    j=2
    _widgets = []


    single_elem_width=int( (int(dim_table[0])/total_columns)/2 )#used for the table cell dimension
    1
    
    for row in range(total_rows):
        current_row = []
        for column in range(total_columns):
            
            #records[][] is the matrix with the data from a database(i'm testing a query with 100 row and 4 column
            label = tk.Label(text_area, text=str(records[row][column]), borderwidth=0, height=1, width=single_elem_width)
            j=j+1
            label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            #label.pack()
            current_row.append(label)
        j=2
        i=i+1
        _widgets.append(current_row)


#The frame
db_frame_admin = tk.Frame(admin_frame, highlightbackground="green", highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=1, width=dimensioni_frame_tabella[0], height=dimensioni_frame_tabella[1])
db_frame_admin.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=FALSE)
```